# Add/replace key>value from variable with jq

Tags: json, path, jq

I want to update (or insert as a new entry if it doesn't already exist) a key=value with bash and jq:

```
jq --arg name "Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name" --arg value "Pluto" '.$name = $value' appsettings.json.tpl > appsettings.json
```

But I got this result:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.$name = $value 
jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:
.$name = $value
jq: 2 compile errors
```

If I add the [ as suggested:

```
jq --arg name "Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name" --arg value "Pluto" '.[$name] = $value' appsettings.json.tpl > appsettings.json
```

I get this result:

```
root@ip-10-1-5-215:~# cat appsettings.json
{
  "Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name": "Pluto"
}
```

But the right result should be like as with this syntax:

```
jq --arg value "Pluto" '.Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name = $value' appsettings.json.tpl > appsettings.json
```

```
root@ip-10-1-5-215:~# cat appsettings.json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Pluto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: No the answer but if you are working on json in bash you can try [fx](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx)

Comment: Use `($name) = $value`

Comment: Will it always be `[0]` for the index of the object you want to check/add ?

Comment: No, it could be also [1] or [n], depending of many items there are there

Comment: @0stone0:Use ($name) = $value

jq --arg name ".Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name" --arg value "Pluto" '($name) = $value' appsettings.json.tpl > appsettings.json
jq: error (at appsettings.json.tpl:2): Invalid path expression with result ".Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `--arg` or `--argjson` to import (and then "evaluate") jq code. These are only meant to import data (as a string or as JSON). You *could* inject code from shell by presetting a shell variable with `.Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name`, and then having it expanded by the shell by wrapping the code inside double quotes, but this is generally regarded bad practice, and introduces other risks on various levels. Better provide the insert location as data, i.e. in a format that jq filters can operate with. One example could be `setpath` which expects the path to be an array of strings (for object fields) and numbers (for array indices).

Using `--argjson` (providing the formatted array) for the path:

```bash
jq --argjson path '["Serilog", "WriteTo", 0, "Name"]' --arg value 'Pluto' 'setpath($path; $value)' input.json
```

Using `--jsonargs` (providing the array's items individuallay) for the path:

```bash
jq --arg value 'Pluto' 'setpath($ARGS.positional; $value)' --jsonargs '"Serilog"' '"WriteTo"' 0 '"Name"' input.json
```

Using `--args` (providing strings only) for the path, and converting strings that look like numbers into actual numbers (to ease formatting the args):

```bash
jq --arg value 'Pluto' 'setpath($ARGS.positional | map(tonumber? // .); $value)' input.json --args Serilog WriteTo 0 Name
```

With an empty input, all of these produce

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Pluto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you would have to write your own parser for expressions of that kind (which is, of course, possible with jq). However, there are other JSON processors that already do have an `eval` function. One of them is [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) which is similar to jq in many ways (and different in a lot of others) but it can read, modify and output JSON data, and has an [`eval`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/eval) function.

```bash
name='.Serilog.WriteTo[0].Name' value='Pluto' yq -oj 'eval(env(name)) = env(value)' input.json
```

```json
{
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Pluto"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks!
I managed following the first approach using sed to fix the syntax of my string, and everything is working as expected!

Thanks!!!!!